# Determine whether there is a line on which all points sit

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to create an algorithm which determines whether there is a horizontal or vertical line on a plane so that for each point on the place, it is either on the vertical line, the horizontal line, or both lines. This algorithm need only be sequential, and return true or false.

I have an idea of what needs to be done, i.e. I need to check each point for its location, but I'm not sure how to check whether its on a line. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Those on the same vertical line share the same ordinate, while those on the same horizontal have the same abscissa...

Comment: The first comment is correct. But if you want just 2 random lines and the points to sit on them you can use their angle with oX. If you go trough all your points and compute the angle created by that point with let's say oX, at the end you will have only 2 different angles. If you end up with more then you can't sit the points on 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort all your points by x co-ordinate and by y-coordinate. If every point is either on a horizontal line or on a vertical line then at least one of these lines must cover at least half the points, and there cannot be more than two horizontal lines like this, or more than two vertical lines like this, because you can't have more than two horizontal lines each with half the points on them.

So by sorting by x-coordinate and looking for lots of points on the same x-coordinate you have at most two candidates for vertical lines, and by sorting by y-coordinate at most two candidates for horizontal lines. For each of these (at most four) candidate lines look at all the points that don't fit on that lines and look at their y-coordinates (or x-coordinates) to see if they all fit on a lines of the other type. If they do, you are done. If not, try the at most three other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You go through each point in sequence and compare their coordinates, knowing that they must share the same x component (abscissa), y component (ordinate), or both. Your goal is to determine these values, and then check that all the points have at least one of them.

- the first point may have one or both correct, so you keep both components as potential correct values,
- the second point should have at least one in common with the first, so you mark the common component as the correct one for either the horizontal (for x) or the vertical line (for y).
- you loop on the next points until all of them share that same component you just found as common between the first two points, if you find one point which isn't on that line, then it must belong to the other, so you've discovered the second correct component,
- Now you check all the remaining points l, if one of them doesn't have either component, the result is false.